# Preferred usage for git bundle

Tags: git

I'm collaborating on a git repository with some folks that can't actually connect to my server, and using an external server is out of the question. We need to use the `git-bundle` approach for disconnected operations.

My question is: which is the preferred usage of this workflow?

## Workflow 1

1. User 1 (U1) creates `file.bundle` and gives it to User 2 (U2).
2. U2 clones from the bundle: `git clone \path\to\file.bundle`
3. A week later, U1 creates an update bundle `file.bundle` and gives it to U2.
4. U2 overwrites `\path\to\file.bundle` and runs `git pull`.

This is the workflow mentioned in `man git-bundle`.

## Workflow 2

1. User 1 (U1) creates `file-xyz123.bundle` and gives it to User 2 (U2).
2. U2 clones from the bundle: `git clone \my\bundles\file-xyz123.bundle`
3. A week later, U1 creates an update bundle `file-abc456.bundle` and gives it to U2.
4. U2 puts it in `\my\bundles` next to `file-xyz123.bundle`.
5. U2 runs `git remote set-url origin \my\bundles\file-abc456.bundle`.
6. U2 runs `git pull`.

This workflow retains a history of the bundles in the folder `\my\bundles`.

Any experience with what works better in practice?